# Нужно найти минимальный среди элементов с четными значениями

Tags: java

Вроде все правильно, но выводит минимальный 1000, хотя если х[0]=0, то должен выводить 0. Массив может быть абсолютно любым.

```
public class lab12 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x;
        int N, min;
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("n = ");
        N = inp.nextInt();

        x = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print("x(" + i + ")= ");
            x[i] = inp.nextInt();
        }
        inp.close();

        min = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if ((i % 2 == 0) && (x[i]) < min) {
                x[i] = min;
                System.out.println("Минимальный элемент " + x[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 0 && x[i] < min) {
        min = x[i];
    }
}
System.out.println("Минимальный even элемент " + min);
```

Comment: а если еще нужно вывести минимальный элемент в виде "Минимальный элемент х[0]=0" . Вместе со значением и номером элемента, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: @user388671 Что значит "как"? Кодом. Покажите Ваши попытки. Лучше - отдельным вопросом.

Comment: Запоминать еще и индекс, изначально выставив его в -1 например

Comment: А что если пользователь введет число больше 10000? Код можно немного улучшить так `min = Integer.MAX_VALUE`